# Visiting Singapore on multiple entry visa, but staying in Johor. How many times can I cross Johor to Singapore

Tags: visas, singapore, multiple-entry

Me & my wife are visiting Singapore & Malaysia for a 14 day trip. We have a 9 week multiple entry visa for Singapore and 1 year multiple entry visa for Malaysia. We am planning to stay at my friend's home in Johor. I would like to spend most of the trip in Singapore (since we did visit many places in Malaysia last year).

So, ideally, around 7 to 10 days we would like to be in Singapore. So, that means, upto 10 border crossings each way - morning from Johor to SG and night time back to Johor.

Is there a chance that we will be denied entry after x times? If yes, what is a safe number of crossings? This is purely tourist visit, so, I am hoping that this is perfectly legal and we can spend more time seeing Singapore without the hotel cost :).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How often can you visit on a multiple-entry pass to Singapore?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18935/how-often-can-you-visit-on-a-multiple-entry-pass-to-singapore)

Comment: I don't think it's an exact duplicate, as the other question is specifically about long term use of visa, while this question, involves a stay well within the 30 days. So while the answer is probably still valid, I think in this case the odds of it actually not causing any problems are better.

Answer (score 8):

As discussed in the answers to [How often can you visit on a multiple-entry pass to Singapore?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18935/how-often-can-you-visit-on-a-multiple-entry-pass-to-singapore), Singapore does not impose any published limit on how often you can visit or how long you can stay, but it's up to the discretion of the immigration officer whether to let you in or not.

In practice, since you're always returning after a single day, I doubt there would be any real problem on either side.  However, simply because the border crossings are **so awkward and time-consuming on foot** — it's a good two hours one way from central JB to central Singapore when you factor in all the immigration and customs and bus queues and whatnot — it would be a somewhat weird thing to repeat this for days on end, and I would expect some questions about what you're doing.  I wouldn't really recommend it either, do you really want to spend several days of your vacation standing in immigration lines?  Get a cheap hotel in Singapore and stay there for a few nights at a time instead.

Comment: I second that. Just to get from either one of the two crossings to the city (after you have cleared both the Singaporean and the Malaysian checkpoints), is more than one hour by bus and train (one-way).