# UAE travel visa, is there a limit to how many times I can use them?

Tags: visas, eu, uae, repeat-visits

I have a Slovak passport and thus can travel visa in UAE for free. They are valid for 30 days.

The trouble is, I want to stay in Dubai for couple months. I heard I can do the visa run (visiting another country and reentering UAE and getting new visas) only 3 times (to be more precise, there is a limit of total 90 'visa days' in 180 day period). I am trying to find source of that information, but without success. All information I can find is either badly outdated or not specific enough

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/18935/36405 on why visa runs are a bad idea. Not a duplicate though, as OP is asking if there's a limit on entries with the free visa from UAE.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of risks, but a lot of people seem to be doing it here and I haven't encountered anyone being banned yet (doesn't mean there aren't people like that out there, I know). I don't plan to stay for more than 5-6 months and I hope I will slip by :)

Comment: I needed more than one. I was waiting for my residency visa process to start (there were some complications so I had to wait few months)

Comment: I am not sure what's the confusion, perhaps I did explain my situation clearly. I don't want to go into much details, but it was like this: I came to Dubai looking for work, I wanted to stay there for maximum allowed time to increase my chances of finding job. On top of that, there were already metioned complications with one company that offered me job. At the time, I thought my travel visa were valid for 30 days only so I was looking for a way to prolong my stay through 2 visa runs. In the end it turned out travel visa were valid for 90 days, so visa run was not required after all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I heard I can do the visa run (visiting another country and reentering
>   UAE and getting new visas) only 3 times (to be more precise, there is
>   a limit of total 90 'visa days' in 180 day period). I am trying to
>   find source of that information, but without success.

Dubai has the normal 90/180 limit for EU nationals and its based on reciprocity and is stated plainly at various sites, here is the snippet from [visitdubai.com](http://www.visitdubai.com/en/travel-planning/travel-tools/visa-and-entry-information) which is the official site of the Dubai Corporation of Tourism & Commerce Marketing:

> - Citizens of the countries listed above can obtain a visa upon arrival for 90 days from the date of entry with their normal passports.
> - It is not possible to extend this visa.
> - Passports should be normal and valid for more than six months.
> - The visa holder can use the 90-day visa upon arrival to be consumed within 180 days from first entry.

From the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mofa.gov.ae/EN/ConsularServices/Pages/Visa-Information.aspx):

> They may stay for a maximum period of 90 days in any 180 – day period.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I got this confirmed at the immigration office. I am aware that this information can be found on the various website, the trouble is that the information is often outdated and outright contradictory.

Answer (score 3):

[Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=SK&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=AE&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by airlines checking passengers, based on up-to-date info from local authorities, states:

> Visa required, except for Nationals of Slovakia for a maximum stay of 90 days.
>
> The max. stay is granted within 180 days.

In other words: the 90/180 rule applies and you can **not** do visa runs